# How to make gallery images responsive?

Tags: gallery, responsive

There are pictures, one below the other, inserted by the editor as a gallery. You can see an example on my page [`here`](http://www.cookinggamesforkids.biz/caw/?works=lavoro-1).

The problem I have is that this gallery of images is not responsive. Resize your browser window to see what I'm talking about -- the images don't change size.

Could you help me make it responsive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for your images to be responsive they require CSS. The CSS will inform the image to stretch 100% of the available space and to automatically adjust the height.

```
img.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Because you don't want to apply this rule to all images, you'll need to add a class on the target image which tells it to use these responsive rules.

```
<img class="responsive" src="somepath/file.jpg" >
```

Add the CSS rule above to your `style.css` then add the class `responsive` to your image.

If you want test if this works first, open the text editor tab of the visual editor and find your image. Add the `style` attribute to the image or just add the relevant styles to the existing styles.

```
<img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="somepath/file.jpg" >
```

Because this is a manual process, the next question might be, 'how do I automatically add a responsive class to an image inserted into the editor?". In that case, you can make sure images added in the visual editor append the responsive class prior to being placed using the [`image_send_to_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/) hook. You can place this in your functions.php or in a plugin but it really only matters in the [`admin`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) section of your site.

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'wpse_20160112_filter_image_send_to_editor', 11, 8);

function wpse_20160112_filter_image_send_to_editor($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
    $responsive_content = str_replace('class="', 'class="responsive ', $html);

    return $responsive_content;
}
```

[Galleries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) work off the same principal. You'll need to establish the class rule ahead of time or add the styles directly to the output of the gallery images using the [`post_gallery`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_gallery) and / or [`img_caption_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode) hook.

---

Luckily for you, the solution is even easier. All you need is this CSS rule to make all your gallery images responsive.

```
.gallery .gallery-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```